# I can't plot this easy formula

Tags: pine-script

```
....
study(title="Cycle Analysis", shorttitle="AC", overlay=true)
p = input(title="Period", type=input.integer, defval=64, minval=1)
y = 1.1
for k = 0 to p
    y := 2*sin(2*3.14*(k/p))
plot(y)
....
```

I would like to plot the result of y that is a sinusoid on the price chart.

An example of the result I would like to obtain

[image]

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm a begginer in the site. I'm using pinescript of trading view. The idea is to plot a sinusoid on the price graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study(title="Help (Cycle Analysis)", shorttitle="AC", overlay=true)
p = input(title="Period", type=input.integer, defval=64, minval=1)
y = 0.0
k = bar_index%p
y := 2*sin(2*3.14*(k/p))
plot(y, style=plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much...I have a question about your code..when you define k why you insert %p near bar_index?

Comment: is for defining a range between 0 and 64?

Comment: @frank, that's right, the `%` operator is used to get the values 0, ..., 63.  
If the answer is complete for you, use the recommendations of the article stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)